# HERE-API using eval and New Function

Tags: here-api

Is there any way to use the Here API without **eval** and **new Function** statements?

(since this kind of statements can be blocked on some environments)

Comment: Please provide specific details like which what is your usecase, api you are trying to use etc. Your question is very generic to provide an appropriate answer.

Comment: The HERE javascript API uses `eval` and `new Function` statements, this kind of statements are blocked by Content Security Policy in our environment ( gecko engine ). The question is there is : is there any version of your api that does not use these expressions?

Comment: btw, thanks for your quick answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this question is specific to the [HERE JavaScript API](https://developer.here.com/develop/javascript-api).  For example, from **mapsjs-core.js** line 154 which is otherwise minimized and obfuscated:

```
function(){eval("var self = arguments[0];"+b)}
```

I'm not going to argue whether or not `eval('...')` and `new Function('...')` are evil/bad practices as the implication from the question is that their usage is blocked anyway in some environments.

As that is the current implementation for the JavaScript API, an alternative is to use the [HERE REST API](https://developer.here.com/develop/rest-apis) directly for whichever services you need.  You will need to handle Ajax requests without the convenience of the JavaScript SDK, but for some libraries and frameworks it may be necessary to have that level of control anyway.  We've recently published some blog posts demonstrating this with [React](https://developer.here.com/blog/here-with-react-location-based-todo-app), [Angular](https://developer.here.com/blog/display-here-maps-angular-web-application), and [Vue](https://developer.here.com/blog/showing-a-here-map-with-the-vue.js-javascript-framework) that may be helpful examples.