# HERE-API using eval and New Function (REPOST)

Tags: javascript, here-api

This question has already been asked:
[HERE-API using eval and New Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52647701/here-api-using-eval-and-new-function)

But this was three years ago so I thought I wouldn't hurt to bring it up again. I don't know if this is the correct way to go about it. If it isn't, I apologize, please do let me know what I need to do instead :)

Are there any version of the HERE API that does not use eval in particular. We are implementing CSP in our app and thus the use of eval came to our attention :)

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment we don't provide" but that might change in the future, as our team is working on the version that will be compatible with the 'unsafe-eval' CSP header in the future.